# $HOME is not defined for root user on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, bash, vim, environment-variables, gdb

On a fresh Ubuntu 14.04 install, the bash environment for the root user does not have `$HOME` defined. I need to run some apps from a root shell, for example:

```
gdb /usr/sbin/apache2
```

This is difficult without a working `$HOME` directory, because apps like `vim` and `gdb` require `$HOME` in the environment, and they are somewhat broken without it. Adding

```
export HOME=/root
```

to `/root/.bashrc` works (though I noticed the `apache2` environment script unsets `$HOME`).

What is the proper way for `HOME=/root` to be defined in the root environment? Is there a reason it wasn't defined in the first place? Should `$HOME` not be defined for the root user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HOME variable is defined in /etc/passwd. The line of the root user should normally look like this:

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
```

The 6th field (separated by colon `:`) defines the home directory and is copied to the HOME environment variable by [PAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluggable_authentication_module); the mechanism of linux to authenticate users.

Comment: Thanks--though I do have `/root` in the normal place in /etc/password. Does that mean something was issuing a `unset HOME` command? It seems like the variable must have been deliberately unset at some point.

Comment: Seems so. You could search for `HOME` in config files and rc scripts: `grep HOME /etc/*` and `grep HOME ~/.*`. Maybe that will reveal some scripts that unset/resets the variable.

Comment: Looks like it was just the `apache2` environment script, which I must have executed a couple times without realizing it. So nothing is wrong with my user config after all...